# What is wrong with my syntax in this 1 line bit of code (pointers and references and dereferences oh my)?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, reference, const-correctness

The code that I am having trouble with is this line:

```
result.addElement(&(*(setArray[i]) + *(rhs.setArray[j])));
```

The + operator in my class is overloaded like this (there are a variety of overloads that can fit in this set, but they all have a similar header):

```
const Rational Rational::operator+(const Rational &rhs) const
```

The setarrays in the code above are both arrays of pointers, but the + operator requires references, which might be the problem.

AddElement, the method of result, has this header:

```
bool Set::addElement(Multinumber* newElement)
```

The Multinumber* in the header is the parent class of Rational, mentioned above. I don't think any of the specific code matters. I'm pretty sure that it is a syntax issue.

My compiler error is:

```
68: error: invalid conversion from 'const Multinumber*' to 'Multinumber*'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: addElement() requires a non-const object, but the + operator returns a const object. Why does it return a const object?

Comment: I guess I may as well turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code has much more serious issues than you can fix by adding a `const` or a typecast somewhere.**

The result of this code will ultimately be a crash somewhere down the line, because you're passing a pointer to a temporary. Once you finish with line of code that calls `addElement`, the pointer will be left dangling, and trying to use the object it points to will either result in nonsense (if you're reading the object) or stack corrpution (if you're writing to the object).

<s>The best way to redefine your code would be to change this to</s>

```
bool Set::addElement(Multinumber newElement) //pass the Multinumber by value
```

and call `addElement` as follows:

```
result.addElement(*setArray[i] + *rhs.setArray[j]);
```

Note that I eliminated all of the extra parentheses because `*` has lower precedence than `[]`, so the parentheses around `setArray[i]` and `setArray[i]` were redundant. I think the code is more readable this way.

---

Well really, if I can guess what's going on here, `setArray` is the internal storage of the `Set` class, so it's type will need to be redefined from `Multinumber**` to `Multinumber*`, in which case the call really should be

```
result.addElement(setArray[i] + rhs.setArray[j]);
```

---

**EDIT** Ugggh. None of the above will actually allow you to keep your polymorphism. You need to call `new Rational` somewhere, and the only reasonable place that I can think of is:

```
result.addElement( new Rational(*setArray[i] + *rhs.setArray[j]) );
```

This will work without having to redefine `Set::addElement`.

---

A better solution would be to redesign the whole thing so that it doesn't depend on polymorphism for numeric classes (because numeric classes really shouldn't be wrapped in pointers in most normal use).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a homework assignment, and the point of the assignment is polymorphism. And I was trying to use the new operator, but I can't because the hierarchy is polymorphic and I can't know whether the set will hold a Rational, Pair, or Complex number at that point. :( Thanks anyway. If you can think of anything else I would immensely appreciate it. I've been working on this for days.

Comment: @Ross: then you can either make `operator+` call `new Rational` and return a pointer (which I think would be a bad idea in real world code), or you can make a new `add` function that does that.

Comment: Genius! I was able to do that in all of the child classes, and then removed the const attribute on the operator+ overload. Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is with `const`

`bool Set::addElement(Multinumber* newElement)` should be `Set::addElement(const Multinumber* newElement)`

Comment: Unless people want to be able to modify the elements of the set.

Comment: that `operator +` function returns a `const` because the Multinumber and Rational classes are immutable objects, it makes no sense to mutate a number in place if you are treating it as if it was a base type like an int

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator +` returns a const object. However, `addElement` requires a non-const object, which is where your compiler error is coming from. Basically, addElement is telling you that it feels at liberty to modify your Multinumber at will, but the `operator +` is beginning you not to modify the returned value.

You should just return a non-const object, unless there's a good reason not to. You're not returning a reference after all.

Of course, if the data in your Set is supposed to be constant and will never be changed, you may as well make `addElement` take a const pointer, and make sure that it internally deals with const pointers EVERYWHERE.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, as my professor does not like a non-const operator+ function, but Iguess I really might have to do so. Of course, then I still have a problem because I would have to pass the returned object into the set as a dynamically allocated pointer, but I can't know what type it is: Rational, Complex, or Pair. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: Again, if it's really constant, your `addElement` can take a const pointer - but that means that it will need to store it internally as a const pointer as well, and it will need to return it as a const pointer in its accessors! As for your other question - are they all derived from a common base class?

Comment: They are. They are all defined from the Multinumber base class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the addElement expecting a non-const where as operator+ is returning a const object.

The fix for the code is cast the return as mentioned below

addElement((Multinumber * )&( *(setArray[i]) + *(rhs.setArray[j])));

If you dont want to cast, as casting might defeat the purpose of type checking here, then you have to change the signature of the addElement. That depending upon your project scope may have impact else where and if this API is public and other developers are using it. Changing signature will impact them also.

So choose wisely.

Comment: Multinumber has no working operator+ overload. The multinumber operator+ is virtual Multinumber& operator+(Multinumber& rhs){return *this}  No code. So I can't cast to multinumber. And I can't cast to a child class because the hierarchy is polymorphic and I don't know what type it will be at any given time. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: casting a `const` away. Bad. Very bad.

Comment: I agree with EboMike ..but if the problem is the to get away from const then above is the solution..Or as I mentioned change the signature...